# Getting array value from user input in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to figure out to return the value from an element in an array from user input. So if a user types 4 it'll print the value of the fourth element in the array. Here's what I have.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int i;
int a[5]={3,4,5,6,7}
scanf("%d",a[i]);
printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

Comment: just subtract your `i` with 1. (`i - 1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to fill the array? What you did above basically does nothing just prints out what the user typed. What you have to do is have the user store the value in int lets say tmp. When you print out the address make sure to decrement by one since arrays start at zero.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int tmp;
int a[5]={4,5,6,7,10};
scanf("%d", &tmp);
printf("%d", a[tmp-1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The format specifier invokes undefined behaviour. Always use the correct one!